# How to empty and fill elements simultaneously in an array one-by-one in angular2 / typescript?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have tried to find the solution for the below problem but no success. Please, help me finding out the solution.

```
let arr = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
arr2 = ["a","b","c","d","e"] 

Required output:  arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
```

The requirement is to empty the arr and fill it simultaneously one by one elements by checking `arr2` contains elements at that position and if yes, fill it with the element present at that place of `arr2` in `arr`, otherwise retain `arr` element if no element is present in `arr2` at that place.

For E.g:- If "1" is removed first,then fill it's place with "a", then,
          "2" is removed fill it's place with "b"......and till last one-by-one.

How to check the output as well?

### app.component.ts

```
  arr = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
    constructor(){
    /*--------method----------*/
    }
```

Comment: Could you give an example array where your `arr2` array doesn't contain the element to be replaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, it can be resolved with forEach().

```
const arr = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
arr.forEach((element, index) => {
  if (arr2[index]) {
    arr[index] = arr2[index];
  }
}
```

But this assumes that the elements are replaced in order. What's the logic for the element replacement?

Comment: To check,  if element is present in arr2 at the position from where element is removed in arr

Comment: I have mentioned in my problem above.

Comment: Just edited based on the requirement. Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
let arr2 = ["a","b","c","d","e"] 
function fillArr(element, index, array) {
  element = this.arr2[index];
}
this.arr.forEach(fillArr);
```